# Google Cloud Resource Manager API: How to list Operations?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform

When doing async things (like creating a Project) with the [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest), the initial call returns an `Operation` struct, which you can then poll using a [get API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/operations/get) to check if the operation completed and if there was an error. However while [many](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations/list) [other](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/reference/latest/operations/list) [APIs](https://developers.google.com/android-partner/reference/rest/v1/operations/list), and it's part of the standard [long running operations prototype](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/4ba9aa8a4a1413b88dca5a8fa931824ee9c284e6/google/longrunning/operations.proto#L67-L72), the Resource Manager API doesn't seem to offer this? This is almost certainly just a case of "vendor didn't think anyone would need it", but throwing up a question in case someone knows a tricky way to list all the pending RM operations.

I am slightly confused because it seems like the web console for Google Cloud does show a list of operations, but I can't quite figure out where those come from. Maybe there is non-public API for it hidden away somewhere?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Which API are you asking about (not API family)?

Comment: Operations https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/operations

Comment: 1) I meant that you should edit your question to clarify/improve. 2) Your comment references an object and not a specific API call.

Comment: There is no API call that I can find for this. I'm asking if one exists.

Comment: You mean you would like to list resource-manager operations that are currently executing? AFAIK there is no published API for this. I checked the API documentation including the ALPHA and BETA versions. Create a Google Issue Tracker requesting this feature: https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker

Comment: Yes, I also checked the docs. I linked them a few comments about. Hence the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from Google that an official API is on their list but no ETA, and there is no workaround.

Also confirmed via network trace that the Cloud Console does indeed use its own magic API that can read all Operations types from every API at the same time, including project creation. But it's very specific to the needs of the console.